# Calculate the integral $\int e^{\sin x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I found this exercise in a book so it probably has an elementary solution.
I didn't succed but I hope maybe someone here will solve it.

$$\int e^{\sin x}\,dx$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D,x%5D

Comment: u right but I dont knew what to say about it, so wird that it come from my teaching book of a course.

Comment: Are you sure it's written exactly like that?

Comment: yes and I'm seeing that it's realy difficult so I leaved it.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) question.

Answer (score 4):

Elementary? Not much. One of the applicable methods explained in

[While solving the integral  of $e^{\sin(x)}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303391/is-frac-pi4l-0z-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1n1-fraci-2n-1)

$\displaystyle \int e^{\sin(x)} dx=I_0(1)x + \frac{\pi}{2}L_0(1) + 2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{I_n(1)}{n} \sin \left ( nx - \frac{n\pi}{2} \right ) $

$I_n(1)$ is rapidly diminishing and the shape of the integral is perfectly explained through this formula.

Comment: Wow. Had always been trying to figure what the Fourier expansion was for this with no luck. Imo this is the most elegant method of expressing this integral.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\int e^{\sin x}\mathrm dx=\int\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin^k(x)}{k!}\right)\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\int\frac{\sin^k(x)}{k!}\mathrm dx\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\left(\int\sin^k(x)\mathrm dx\right)$$

where the swap between the summation and the integral is possible because the series converges uniformly for $x\in\Bbb R$. But I dont think that we can go far further than the last expression.

However, from the last expression, we can approach easily to any desired level of error the value of any definite integral.

We knows too that

$$I_n=\frac1n((n-1)I_{n-2}-\cos x(\sin x)^{n-1})$$

for $I_n:=\int\sin^n(x)\mathrm dx$. But as @MrYouMath said in the end we will need numerical methods, and we can use it directly in the original integral, by example using any kind of Simpson's rule.

Comment: You could also expand the sine function.

Comment: @MrYouMath ya, I know but... And we can find a recurrence relation to write $\int \sin^n(x)\mathrm dx$

Comment: But in the end, it is easier to calculate the integral directly by numerical methods :D.

Comment: it cen be a nice exercise to show in that way that $\int_{0}^\infty{e^{\sin(x)}}<\infty$. thank u for that conclution.

Comment: @YardenSharabi [if you graph the function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dmdt01y5xt) you can see that $\int_0^\infty e^{\sin (x)}\mathrm dx=\infty$

Comment: u right I did a mistake. Thanke u again!

Answer (score 2):

Copying my answer to the almost duplicate [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2468961/442)

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117545/442

Although this indefinite integral has no known closed form, certain definite integrals are known...
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}\;dx = \pi\;I_0(1) ,
$$
where $I_0$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1)