# Calculating the integral $\int e^{\sin(mx+n)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

I know that: $$\int e^{mx+n}\,dx=\frac{1}{m}\cdot e^{mx+n}$$
But I was wondering if its possible to calculate $\int e^{\sin(mx+n)}\,dx$. As I understand it is not trivial (looked at the solution as WolframAlpha) but how to achieve it with Taylor series at least?

Comment: [This might help you out.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213128/calculate-the-integral-int-e-sin-x-dx)

Comment: Writing the sine in exponential form might show you something.

Comment: not sure if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do not expect a closed form.

Considering $$I=\int e^{\sin(mx+n)}\,dx$$ let 
$$mx+n=y \implies x=\frac{y-n}{m}\implies dx=\frac{dy}{m}$$ to make
$$I=\frac 1 m \int e^{\sin(y)}\,dy=\frac 1 m \int \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{sin^k(y)}{k!}\,dy=\frac 1 m \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\int sin^k(y)\,dy$$ and use the reduction formula
$$\int\sin^k(y)\,dx=
-\frac{\cos (y)  \sin^{k-1}(y)}{k} + \frac{(k-1)}{k} \int \sin^{k-2} (y)\, dy$$

For illustration purposes, consider $m=2$, $n=3$ and integrate between $0$ and $5$ and consider the partial sums (up to $p$). You would obtain
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 0 & 5.00000 \\
 1 & 4.05128 \\
 2 & 5.23616 \\
 3 & 5.12575 \\
 4 & 5.19944 \\
 5 & 5.19500 \\
 6 & 5.19704 \\
 7 & 5.19695 \\
 8 & 5.19698 
\end{array}
\right)$$